# Flip-flop contamination delay definition in Weste and Harris book

Tags: flipflop, sequential-logic

In Weste and Harris book "CMOS VLSI Design: A Circuits and Systems Perspective" at the paragraph 10.4.2 "Characterizing Sequencing Element Delays" ( pag 405 in the fourth edition), are presented formal definitions for setup time, hold time, propagation and contamination delay.
This is the screenshot with the definitions.

[image]

I didn't understand the last one. Looking at figure 10.35, tCQ is a propagation delay.
Why  the value of propagation delay when the input arrives early is used to define the contamination delay ?

Comment: I think we need more context. I've been scratching my head, trying to figure out why anybody would care about D-to-Q delay in a flip-flop.